# Is there a way to control memory consumption in .NET globally

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, task-parallel-library

Is there a way to control memory consumption in .NET globally?

I am aware of [MemoryFailPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.memoryfailpoint.aspx) but I need to restrict it globally in my whole app. `MemoryFailPoint` needs to be created for each next operation - and get disposed.

And since I am doing something heavily palatalized, I am not sure if `MemoryFailPoint` would not meddle with TPL.

Just for fun instantiate an instance of this class:

```
class Bomb
{
    public Bomb()
    {
        var t = new Task<Bomb>(() => new Bomb());
        t.Start();

        t.Wait();
        Next = t.Result;
    }

    string TNT = new string('*', 1024 * 640);

    public Bomb Next;
}
```

Comment: Nothing direct, but this question addresses the problem too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852062/limiting-process-memory-with-maxworkingset

Comment: Could you explain in more detail why are you trying to do this? Are you trying to protect against potentially buggy plug-in, or something like that?